# Entity Framework Code First unique index foreign key throws DbUpdate Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

Here's the entites and context code:

```
public class Family
{
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public String address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> FamilyMembers { get; set; }
}
public class Member
{
    [Index("MemberUniqueID", IsUnique = true)]
    public int MemberID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)] [Index("MemberUniqueIndex", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public String name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)] [Index("MemberUniqueIndex", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public String surname { get; set; }

    public int age { get; set; }
    public int FamilyID { get; set; }
    public virtual Family Family { get; set; }
}
public class Bicycle
{
    public int BicycleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Owner { get; set; }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext : base () { }
    public DbSet<Member> MemberDB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Family> FamilyDB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bicycle> BicycleDB { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I add a few examples of each, add them and `SaveChanges();`. Then I try to run this code:

```
    public void bicycle_set_FK(int IDbicycle, int IDmember)
{
       var bicycleToFind = BicycleDB.Find(IDbicycle);
       var memberToSetAsFK = MemberDB.Find(IDmember);
       bicycleToFind.Owner = memberToSetAsFK;
       SaveChanges();
}
```

And as a result, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll Cannot insert duplicate key row in object
>   'dbo.Members' with unique index 'MemberUniqueIndex'. The duplicate key
>   value is (John, Smith). The statement has been terminated.

The weird thing is, if I run that method simultaneously while adding the examples, the method works fine and sets the FK as expected. But if I first add the examples with the first run of the code, and I try to set FKs on the second run of the code, it throws that exception.

## EDIT:

Okay, so I've done as recommended and after reading the artice you linked I have this:

```
[ForeignKey("MemberID")]
public int? OwnerID { get; set; }
public virtual Member MemberID { get; set; }
```

And the method looks like this:

```
public void bicycle_set_FK(int IDbicycle, int IDmember)
{
   var bicycleToFind = BicycleDB.Find(IDbicycle);
   bicycleToFind.MemberID = null;
   bicycleToFind.OwnerID = IDmember;
   SaveChanges();
}
```

But this generates a new problem:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Members'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Members'. The duplicate key value is
>   (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

The values I use are 1 and 3 (`bicycle_set_FK(1, 3);`). Members contain 3 rows with IDs: 1, 2 and 3. So where does it find that zero, since it's not in the database nor do I enter it at any point in the code?

And one more thing: the article doesn't mention how to solve that problem in a one-to-many relationship. How do I add FK between Family and Member? Do I add some property such as `public List<Member> FamilyMembersFK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework is re-adding your Owner(Member). There are a couple of ways around this, but since you have the FK try this:

```
public class Bicycle
{
    public int BicycleID { get; set; }

    public int MemberID { get; set; }  // You can call this ownerId, but then you need to setup the relationship with annotation or fluent
    public virtual Member Owner { get; set; }
}

public void bicycle_set_FK(int IDbicycle, int IDmember)
{
   var bicycleToFind = BicycleDB.Find(IDbicycle);
   // var memberToSetAsFK = MemberDB.Find(IDmember); ** Don't need to do this since you have FK **
   bicycleToFind.MemberId = IDmember;
   SaveChanges();
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

EDIT:  First, I highly recommend you follow some convention when naming your navigation classes and keys. You are calling your navigation class "MemberId" - that is very confusing. If you want the FK to be OwnerId, go with something like this:

```
public int? OwnerID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("OwnerID")]
public virtual Member Owner { get; set; }
```

Second, you don't need this annotation:

```
//[Index("MemberUniqueID", IsUnique = true)]  **MemberID will be a identity key by default so it will have a unique index created.
public int MemberID { get; set; }
```

Now you can insert an existing owner like this:

```
public void bicycle_set_FK(int IDbicycle, int IDmember)
{
   var bicycleToFind = BicycleDB.Find(IDbicycle);
   bicycleToFind.OwnerID = IDmember;  // Don't worry about the nav class, just set the FK
   SaveChanges();
}
```

Regarding the one to many, you already have that configured with:

```
public virtual ICollection<Member> FamilyMembers { get; set; }
```

So to add a new member:

```
var newMember = new Member {
    Name = "Joe",
    Surname = "Smith",
    Age = 30,
    FamilyId = familyId
};

context.Members.Add(newMember);
SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've followed your instructions, but unfortunately they caused more problems. See the edit in my post

Comment: See edit. You are dealing with 2 issues. First, get you models right, then you can deal with the CRUD code and repository. Many options available.