# Error when using code first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlite

I am wondering why am I getting error when using code first but not when database first. To give you a quick look at my application this is my class:

```
[Table("Votes")]
public class Vote {
    [Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Answer")]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

And after this line of code:

```
Vote v = new Vote();
v.UserId = 1;
v.AnswerId = 1;

using (var context = new DatabaseContext()) {
    context.Votes.Add(v);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am getting error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

So the error happens when I am using `code first` with `SQLExpress` database. When I am using `database first` with `SQLite` database it is working like a charm. The same classes, but no error.

I noticed, that to avoid getting error I have to initialize `v.User` and `v.Answer`. But why? In `database first` it was unnecessary.

Comment: Could you try setting them to null and trying?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Yes and it is still not working. It is working only when I create new instances of `User` and `Answer` and assing them to `v` object properties.

Comment: Can you please add your model builder please

Comment: You could try the alternative method of specifying foreign keys: `[ForeignKey("UserId")] public virtual User User { get; set; }`, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35655336/6741868). Or, as suggested in the first part of that answer, you could try omitting `[ForeignKey("Answer")]` entirely and see if EF can automatically recognize the keys.

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: Do you have userid 1 and answerid 1 in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not coded db context class. You need to create  dbcontext class eg.

```
using System.Data.Entity;  
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;  
using Votes.Models;  
namespace vote.Context  
{  
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext  
    {  
        public DatabaseContext() : base("VotesDatabase")  
        { }  
        public DbSet<Vote> Votes{ get; set; }  
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  
        {  
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Here is example for you understand a basic codefirst MVC appliaction. [Creating MVC Applications Using Entity Framework Code First Approach](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-mvc-application-using-entity-framework-code-first-approach/)